# UNIX setting extended attributes setxattr

Tags: java, unix, attributes

**- How to write UserDefinedFileAttributes in UNIX ?**

or

**- How to set setxattr in UNIX ?**

---

I'm using a java program i made in Windows on the UNIX server. As part of this i write extended file info to a file using UserDefinedFileAttributeView.

I have a test to see if a file system supports UserDefinedFileAttributeView:

```
public static String[] supportedFileAttributeViews() {
    final FileSystem defaultFS = FileSystems.getDefault();
    return defaultFS.supportedFileAttributeViews()
           .toArray(new String[defaultFS.supportedFileAttributeViews().size()]);
}
```

On the UNIX server this gives me:

```
"basic" "owner" "user"  "unix"  "dos"   "posix"
```

So i guess that it is possible to write UserDefinedFileAttributes to the file ( -->"user")

But if java writes to file i get an error:

```
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: .... 
Error writing extended attribute 'test': Operation not supported
at sun.nio.fs.LinuxUserDefinedFileAttributeView.write
(LinuxUserDefinedFileAttributeView.java:246)
........
```

my code to write UserDefinedFileAttributes:

```
public static boolean writeCustomMETAfile(String filepath,String name, String value) {
    boolean succes = false;
    try {
        Path file = Paths.get(filepath);
        UserDefinedFileAttributeView userView = Files.getFileAttributeView(file, UserDefinedFileAttributeView.class);
        //userView.write(name, Charset.defaultCharset().encode(value));

         final byte[] bytes = value.getBytes("UTF-8");
         final ByteBuffer writeBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytes.length);
         writeBuffer.put(bytes);
         writeBuffer.flip();

        userView.write(name, writeBuffer);
        succes = true;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return succes;
}
```

I have been searching StackOverflow and all kinds of manuals (UNIX) and other web sources but with no luck uptill now.

on the UNIX commandline:

```
man 2 setxattr
```

gives me some info and i tried all kinds of chmod settings.

Could it be in i-nodes?:

```
An i-node holds most of the metadata for a
Unix file — on classic Unix, it holds all but the
i-node number itself
```

So the question is:
- How to write UserDefinedFileAttributes in UNIX / How to set setxattr in UNIX ?

Comment: What filesystem you are using on this partition?

Comment: Hi @SubOptimal : TYPE="ext4" found with terminal command: blkid in UNIX

Comment: Which Java version do you use? Please mention also the update version (e.g. 1.7.0_40).

Comment: Hi @SubOptimal : Java version (found in Eclipse - Properties -Java Compiler 1.8 with compliance J2SE-1.5) Terminal java -version -> 1.8.0_31 -> SE runtime environment build 1.8.0_31-b13 (in windows development environment) and on UNIX teminal: java version "1.7.0_75" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_75-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.75-b04, mixed mode)

Answer (score 1):

Find below a small snippet which will read and write the xattr on a file.
For simplicity there is no appropriate exception handling.

```
Path path = Paths.get("/tmp/foobar");

// you should get the filestore for the path
FileStore fileStore = Files.getFileStore(path);
System.out.println("fileStore     : " + fileStore);

// check if the filesystem supports xattr
//
// I found out that the reported state might be wrong for ext3/ext4
//
// if you create following properties file it will be correct
// echo "ext4=user_attr" > $JAVA_HOME/lib/fstypes.properties
//
// keep in mind that it's possible that your ext3/ext4 does not support xattr
// might be related to: kernel configuration, mount options, etc.
boolean supportsXattr = fileStore.supportsFileAttributeView(UserDefinedFileAttributeView.class);
System.out.println("supports xattr: " + supportsXattr);

// get the file attribute view
UserDefinedFileAttributeView view = Files.getFileAttributeView(path, UserDefinedFileAttributeView.class);
String xattrName = "xattr-foo";
String xattrValue = "dummy-value";

Charset defaultCharset = Charset.defaultCharset();
if (view.list().contains(xattrName)) {
    // get the size of the attribute value
    int xattrSize = view.size(xattrName);
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(xattrSize);

    // read the attribute value
    int bytesRead = view.read(xattrName, buffer);

    // decode the buffer and print it
    buffer.flip();
    xattrValue = defaultCharset.decode(buffer).toString();
    System.out.println("xattr name    : " + xattrName);
    System.out.println("xattr value   : " + xattrValue);
} else {
// edit: System.out.println to System.out.printf in the next line
    System.out.printf("file has no xattr [%s]%n", xattrName);
}

// write the current value back reversed, can be checked next run
// or on command line
String newXattrValue = new StringBuilder(xattrValue).reverse().toString();
view.write(xattrName, defaultCharset.encode(newXattrValue);
```

**edit** I pushed a complete example on [github](https://github.com/jugsaar/jugsaar-meeting-9/blob/master/talks/java-nio2/src/main/java/de/jugsaar/meeting9/nio2/fileattributes/UserExtendedAttributes.java). It should also work on NTFS partitions on Windws.

The extended attributes can be set on Linux as

```
setfattr -n user.foo_name -v bar_value /tmp/foobar
```

and can be retrieved as

```
getfattr -n user.foo_name /tmp/foobar
```

Comment: Hi @SubOptimal : Thanks. I made a test on Windows: (supports xattr: true) and UNIX:
supports xattr: false
file has no xattr [xattr-foo]. I will try to change Java to 1.7 and see if that works...

Comment: @irJvV You need to run the snippet at least twice. In the first run it's expected that the file do not have the xattr `xattr-foo` and will be written in the first run. In the second run it should be read (assuming the filesystem really supports xattr). I will provide more details later, incl. the Linux commands.

Comment: Hi @SubOptimal : Thanks, i ran it multiple times. I tried Java 1.7.  I made a function: public static boolean supportsFileAttributeView(String filepath) {...} that returns a boolean:  fileStore.supportsFileAttributeView(UserDefinedFileAttributeView.class); and in UNIX the return is FALSE -> It is more a UNIX thing than a JAVA thing i FEAR.

Comment: @irJvV Have a look at my updated answer. I pushed a complete example on github.

Comment: A great manny thanks for all the effort you put into this. ;^) It is very much appriciated.    I fear that it has to do with UNIX and the settings there. The code works for me fine in Windows and Linux (Ubuntu) but not on UNIX : see the response on the terminal command. | command: $ setfattr -n user.foo_name -v bar_value example_data.tsv
 | response by UNIX: setfattr: example_data.tsv: Operation not supported

Comment: @irJvV What is your `UNIX`? Maybe the filesystem is not mounted wiht xattr support, the kernel is build without xattr support, or something else. ;-)

Comment: UNIX is like Windows and Linux (Linux is kind of family of UNIX) a platform. It is very stable and used used on servers a lot. (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_File_System ) I will ask the System Admin to take a look at this and if i find a solution (like mounting the filesystem) i will report that here (may take a while) Thanks again !

Comment: @irJvV It would be nice to know why it was not working for you. Could you please also add all necessary details (filesystem, kernel, mount options, and also inlcude version numbers, where it's applicable).

Comment: I will ask the System Administrator those things. I do not know all the details / have no permissions in the unix file system. As soon as i get info back i will let you know too. It may take a while because it takes time for them to response back to me.